# Can't connect to SVN repository via HTTPS using AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssl, ankhsvn

I’m using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 and AnkhSVN.

When I click “*Add Solution to Subversion*” and paste my repository URL into the designated field, nothing happens; I do not get asked to accept a certificate.

When I attempt connection via http (and not https), I’m asked for a username and password (as expected). As a temporary course of action, I simply accept the non-encrypted connection. After successfully committing my test files, I go under “*Pending Changes*” and click “*Switch To*” (the URL field) and choose “*Other*”. I change the address to https, and the following error message pops up:

> An internal error occurred:
>
> SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Unable to connect to a repository
>   at URL ‘[my repository URL]’ OPTIONS of ‘[my repository URL]’: SSL
>   handshake failed: SSL disabled due to lack of entropy [https URL]

I've tried using both Assembla and Google repositories with the same result.

Back in January of this year, the last time I actually used SVN, I didn’t have this problem. When I load this old January project, it can no longer connect to the repository via https.

The only thing that’s changed since then, I think, is upgrading AnkhSVN.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in SharpSvn's compilation of OpenSSL when the LanMan Windows service is disabled. The bug has been fixed in recent AnkhSVN and SharpSvn versions.